# performing operations after uploading a CSV file in shiny [R]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made a upload button via which I am uploading a .CSV file[dataset] in shiny.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,3,7,8,9,2),B=c(3,7,8,9,2,1,2,3,4,5,6),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2))
```

In ui.R :

```
fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
     accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
     actionButton("uploaddata", "upload"),
```

I want to perform operations such as "a+b" and "a-b" over the dataset and add it as a new column in my dataset with the help of actionButton.

Problem 1: I tried to use tableOutput() function to display the DATA in shinyapp but it is displaying DATA dataframe in R console instead.

In server.R:

```
DATA <- dataframe %>% group_by(C) %>% mutate(A) %>% 
mutate(B) %>% mutate(add = (A+B)) %>% mutate(sub = (A-B))
```

Problem 2: I want to use DATA as an input for making ggplots of (add, sub)

Comment: Without your `ui.r` and `server.r` it is hard to tell what is going on with Problem 1.  What is going wrong on Problem 2?

Comment: @JohnPaul For problem 1: I have two columns a and b for which I am calculating `a+b` and `a-b`. Now when I am trying to display the whole table in the shinyapp and its not displaying.. I don't know where I am doing wrong.
_For problem 2: I don't really know how to do it.!_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
                accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
        tableOutput('table'),
        plotOutput('plot')
        ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

        dataframe<-reactive({
                if (is.null(input$datafile))
                        return(NULL)                
                data<-read.csv(input$datafile$datapath)
                data<- data %>% group_by(C) %>% mutate(A) %>% 
                        mutate(B) %>% mutate(add = (A+B)) %>% mutate(sub = (A-B))
                data
        })
        output$table <- renderTable({
                dataframe()
        })
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
                if(!is.null(dataframe()))
                        ggplot(dataframe(),aes(x=X,y=add))+geom_point()
        })
})
```

I removed the action button because `fileInput` will load the file directly once the user has chosen it. 
In the `server.R`, the loaded `dataframe` is stored in a reactive value, you can call `dataframe()` when you want to make a plot/render the table to get the dataframe.

You might also want to code to check that your csv file has A and B as column etc.

Comment: Thank you @NicE I have tried your code. But In the second problem, I am getting an error `Aesthetics must either be length 1 or the same length as the data problems: A, B`.. How can I resolve that?

Comment: this is what I have tried: 

`ggplot(data.frame(),aes=(y=A,x=B,colour=C))+geom_point`

for this it's returning the `Aesthetics` Error

Comment: Works fine for me, there's no equal after `aes`, try removing it.

Comment: my bad, i mistyped it while writing the comment. there is no `=` I have used in my command in R

Comment: also, is your code `data.frame()` or `dataframe()`, the variable is `dataframe()` without dots, maybe should change that to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Nick sorry. mistype. it is dataframe()

Comment: Every time the function dataframe() is called, the csv is loaded from disk, right? That means the data is read multiple times. Isn't there an easier way in R-shiny to make variables available throughout the whole server function?